# how does the red color box mark line add?

Tags: reactjs

To set the color of the start value, end value, and complete tick marks in React.js while using the provided tick-related properties, you can use inline styling with conditional rendering. Here's an example:

[red box - React Linear Gauge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAPNf.png)

npm install --save igniteui-react-core

npm install --save igniteui-react-gauge

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

import { IgrLinearGauge } from 'igniteui-react-gauges';
import { IgrLinearGaugeModule } from 'igniteui-react-gauges';

IgrLinearGaugeModule.register();

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container sample">
            <IgrLinearGauge
                 height="800px"
                 width="80px"
                 minimumValue={0} 
                 maximumValue={10000} interval={1000}
                 orientation="vertical"

                

                 tickBrush="red"
                 ticksPreTerminal={5000}
                 ticksPostInitial={0}
                 tickStrokeThickness={2}
                 tickStartExtent={0.5}
                 tickEndExtent={0.05}

                 minorTickCount={4}
                 minorTickBrush="red"
                 minorTickEndExtent={0.05}
                 minorTickStartExtent={0.15}
                 minorTickStrokeThickness={1}

                 fontBrush="DodgerBlue"
                 
                 
                 />


                 
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```